# Sort two dimensional array with different lengths

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting

Hi fellow programmers,

I am trying to sort a two dimensional array. This array represent a collection of objects which has a property which have a value in the list underneath. So the original list does not have to be saved.

The starting situation is:

```
var list = new List<string>
        {
            "10-158-6",
            "11-158-6",
            "90-158-6",
            "20-15438-6",
            "10-158-6",
            "10-158-6-3434",
            "10-1528-6"
        };
```

The result should be

```
var list = new List<string>
            {
                "10-158-6",
                "10-158-6",
                "10-1528-6"
                "10-158-6-3434",
                "11-158-6",
                "20-15438-6",
                "90-158-6",
            };
```

It should be first ordered on the first part -> then the second -> etc. etc.

I think it is almost impossible to sort these strings so I converted it to a two-dimensional list. I found different solutions to sort multi dimensional list but none can be used for this problem. Also I do not have a clue where to start...

Anyone has an idea how to write a sorting algorithm that doesn't have unnecessary huge big O?

Thanks in advance!

Jeroen

Comment: What difference with the lexicographic order ? Did you try to sort the strings directly?

Comment: Jep, that was the first thing I tried. Other characters but numbers are always sorted before numbers. So 10-1528 comes before 10-158- while sorted, it should be otherwise

Comment: Why do you write that it is impossible to sort multi dimensional list for this problem? Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Using version will do it ? `var versions = list.Select(x => new Version(x.Replace('-','.'))).ToList();
            versions.Sort();` Would that do the trick or the switch from dash to dot is a no go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Sort` method; let's implement a *general case* with *arbitrary long* numbers:

**Code:**

```
  var list = new List<string>() {
    "10-158-6",
    "11-158-6",
    "90-158-6",
    "20-15438-6",
    "10-158-6",
    "10-158-6-3434",
    "10-1528-6",
    "123456789012345678901234567890"
  };

  list.Sort((left, right) => {
    var x = left.Split('-');
    var y = right.Split('-');

    // Compare numbers:
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length); ++i) {
      // Longer number is always bigger: "123" > "99"
      int r = x[i].Length.CompareTo(y[i].Length);

      // If numbers are of the same length, compare lexicographically: "459" < "460"
      if (r == 0)
        r = string.CompareOrdinal(x[i], y[i]);

      if (r != 0)
        return r;
    }

    // finally, the more items the bigger: "123-456-789" >  "123-456"
    return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
  });

  // Let's have a look at the list after the sorting
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list));
```

**Outcome:**

```
10-158-6
10-158-6
10-158-6-3434  // <- please, note that since 158 < 1528
10-1528-6      // <- "10-158-6-3434" is before "10-1528-6" 
11-158-6
20-15438-6
90-158-6
123456789012345678901234567890
```

Comment: No this is @Dmitry has it right! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Those look like Version number. If a change from Dash to Dot are not a big change you can simply use C# [Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "10-158-6",
    "11-158-6",
    "90-158-6",
    "20-15438-6",
    "10-158-6",
    "10-158-6-3434",
    "10-1528-6"
};

var versions = list.Select(x => new Version(x.Replace('-','.'))).ToList();
versions.Sort();
```

[LiveDemo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VOTbSs)